# EXCEL spreadsheet -- matrices product term by term

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, formula, product

I have two table with figures with dimension 9*9. I would like to compute

sum(aij*bij) over j

with obvious notation with one formula only.

For now, I am first computing a 9*9 table filled with aij*bij in each cell, and then in a new column I am doing a sum over columns of values in this 9*9 table. It is two step. I would like to do that in one step to save space and time.

What is syntax ?

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming questions. better suited to Super User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach here - use array `SUM` formula: `=SUM(A1:I1*K1:S1)`. However, as you type it into cell, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> **instead of usual** <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. As a result, this formula will be displayed as `{=SUM(A1:I1*K1:S1)}` - brackets indicate that this is an array formula. However, they should NOT be manually added.

@chuff answer is absolutely correct and I upvoted it, but using array formulas has at least 1 advantage: with them you may do much more magic tricks which are not / hardly implemented using `SUMPRODUCT` or any similar functions.

Please also see **Remark** section there: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumproduct-HP005209293.aspx

Use this sample file as a demo for both solutions: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xr8iif920uqpqf/SUMPRODUCT.xlsx

Choose any solution which is more suitable for you! (:

Comment: Then, is this formula correct `{=SUM(POWER($M4*C32:K32-C61:K61,2))}` if I want SUM((aij*bij-cij)^2) over j ? I wonder if i can mix a SUMPRODUCT with an add/sub operation.

Comment: You can use SUM or SUMPRODUCT for that formula, with the rest of the formula identical - the advantage of SUMPRODUCT is that you don't need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use SUMPRODUCT formulas to sum products over columns.

If your original arrays are in ranges A1:I9 and K1:S9, then the first entry in your result array would be =SUMPRODUCT(A1:I1, K1:S1). Copying this formula down for eight rows more gives you the rest of the result elements..

Summing the products over all elements would be even easier: SUMPRODUCT(A1:I9,K1:S9)